# How to plot with 2 y scaled axes and shared X axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a floating clustered bar chart with some y axis on the same graph with some scatter plot data that has the same X units but different y units.

I've tried to follow the example in the following post using the function axis.twinx()

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html

Since my bar chart has an x max at 2400 and my scatter chart has one around 1600 the new combined chart with shared x axes will not match the displayed axis with the values on the scatter plot.

Eg.  Scatter plot final value (1600, y)  is in position that graphically shows x =2400 but the points show correctly as (1600, y) when hovering over the point.

How can I do this 2 scaled Y axes with the correct scaling for the second axes in x?

```py
plt,clf()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplot()

#part of my bar graph code
#pw_min = plt.barh(y_pos, w_min,gwidth)
ax1.pw_max52 = plt.barh(y_pos+4*gw, w_max52, height = gw, left = w_min, color = 'b')
ax1.pw_max89 = plt.barh(y_pos+2*gw, w_max89, height = gw, left = w_min, color = 'r')
#ax.twinx()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

#plotting the scatter plot on the second axes we just made with twinx()
hwscat = ax2.plot(xsca, ysca, 'g.',xscb, yscb, 'b.')

plt.show()
```

It seems like the second ax is just placing the plot at locations in space but isn't placing them related to their correct x Values.

Comment: All axes are scaled correctly by default. Your code isn't runnable, so one cannot find out what problem you face. (See [mcve])